# How to display Image when Text is null or empty in GridView and viceversa?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-listview, android-studio

I have created a gridview with both image and text in it.
Now i want to display only Image when text is empty or null.
That is show image when text is empty or  "" and hide image when text is present.

Here is my code in fragment ...

```
public class fragment_detail_both extends Fragment {

GridView mGridView;
ProgressBar progress;
List<SampleTry> rowItems;




public static final String[] web = new String[]{

        "Pinterest",
        "Quora",
        "Twitter",
        "Vimeo msndjkcns nzcjkxns nkjcsns",
        "WordPress",
        "Youtube",
        "Stumbleupon",
        "SoundCloud msnd  hekko sdjkl kdksdon",
        "Reddit",
        "Blogger",
        "Github",
        "Instagram",
        "Blogger ",
        "Facebook",
        "Flickr",
        "Pinterest",
        "Quora",
        "Twitter",
        "Vimeo",
        "WordPress",
        "Youtube",
        "Stumbleupon",
        "SoundCloud",
        "Reddit"
};
public static final Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7,
        R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9,
        R.drawable.image10,
        R.drawable.image11,
        R.drawable.image12,
        R.drawable.image13,
        R.drawable.image14,
        R.drawable.image15,
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
        R.drawable.image5,
        R.drawable.image6,
        R.drawable.image7,
        R.drawable.image8,
        R.drawable.image9,
        R.drawable.image10,
        R.drawable.image11,
        R.drawable.image12,
        R.drawable.image13
};


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_both, container, false);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < web.length; i++) {
        SampleTry item = new SampleTry(web[i], images[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    Detail_adaptor adapter = new Detail_adaptor(getActivity(), rowItems);
    mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    progress = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detail_progress);
    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    return view;
}


}
```

and Detail_adapter is

```
public class Detail_adaptor extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
List<SampleTry> rowItems;


public Detail_adaptor(Context context, List<SampleTry> items) {

    mContext = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder();

            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    SampleTry sampleTry = (SampleTry) getItem(position);

    holder.textView.setText(sampleTry.getWeb());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(sampleTry.getImagesId());

    return convertView;
}


 }
```

and SampleTry class is

```
public class SampleTry {
String web;
int imagesId;

public SampleTry(String web, int imagesId) {
    this.web = web;
    this.imagesId = imagesId;
}

public String getWeb() {
    return web;
}

public void setWeb(String web) {
    this.web = web;
}

public int getImagesId() {
    return imagesId;
}

public void setImagesId(int imagesId) {
    this.imagesId = imagesId;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return web;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside **getView()** function you have to use something like this

```
...
if(sampleTry.getWeb().isEmpty() || sampleTry.getWeb() == null){
  holder.imageView.setImageResource(sampleTry.getImagesId());
  holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
  holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
  holder.textView.setText(sampleTry.getWeb());
  holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
...
```

instead of

```
holder.textView.setText(sampleTry.getWeb());
holder.imageView.setImageResource(sampleTry.getImagesId());
```

Have fun.

Comment: ya working for the first time but when i scroll down  the image the image is not showing again when scroll up again.
what should i do??

Comment: Try this code. If it's help please accept my answer.

Comment: Its worked, Thanks bro (Y) 
I will always perform my civil duty.
Greatly helped.

Comment: I am glad to here that. Have fun dude. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this ..

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MyViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new MyViewHolder();

            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    SampleTry sampleTry = (SampleTry) getItem(position);

    if (sampleTry.getWeb() != null && ! sampleTry.getWeb().isEmpty()) {
        holder.textView.setText(sampleTry.getWeb());
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(sampleTry.getImagesId());
        holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: ya working for the first time but when i scrool the image the image is not showing again.
what should i do??

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is because need to toggle visibility of view for every row.  Sorry for my clumsy mistake.

Comment: great worked, and completely get the idea that needed
but @EliaszKubala also give same suggest .